# pointer to const int using smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to create a smart pointer (`unique_ptr`) to a value returned as `const int&` but my issue can be summed up as easily as:

```cpp
 const int value = 5;
 const int * ptr{nullptr};
 ptr = &value;
```

This works, and compile as expected. When trying to the same using smart pointer:

```cpp
 const int value = 5;
 std::unique_ptr<const int> ptr{nullptr};
 ptr = &value;
```

With this I get the compile error:

```
no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::unique_ptr<const int, std::default_delete<const int>> = const int *
```

Is it possible to get the same behaviour as normal C pointers?

EDIT:
I see that my original question was too simplified: here is the bit more advanced version:

```cpp
int value = 5;
const int& getValue(){
    return value;
};
std::unique_ptr<const int> ptr1{nullptr};
const int * ptr2{nullptr};

ptr1 = std::make_unique<const int>(getValue());
ptr2 = &getValue();
std::cout << "ptr1: " << *ptr1 << "\n";
std::cout << "ptr2: " << *ptr2 << "\n";
value++;
std::cout << "ptr1: " << *ptr1 << "\n";
std::cout << "ptr2: " << *ptr2 << "\n";
```

This prints out:

```cpp
ptr1: 5
ptr2: 5

ptr1: 5
ptr2: 6
```

As you see the behaviour is a bit different, now I believe it is because `make_unique` makes a copy of the value in the pointed memory address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` can't be assigned by raw pointer directly; you can use [`reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). But you shouldn't assign the address of `value`, (which is destroyed when get out of the scope automatically), `std::unique_ptr` will try to `delete` the pointer and that leads to UB.

You might want

```
int value = 5; // we'll constructor a new object, value doens't need to be const
std::unique_ptr<const int> ptr{nullptr};
ptr = std::make_unique<const int>(value); // construct a new object and pass the ownership to ptr
```

**EDIT**

For the purpose of using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers),

> Smart pointers are used to make sure that an object is deleted if it is no longer used (referenced).

You shouldn't use smart pointers if you don't want the smart pointer manage the object, or can't let the smart pointer own the object. For this special case, I think it's just fine to use raw pointer.

Comment: Notice that `value` no longer requires to be `const`.

Comment: Thank you this solved the compile error, but I updated my question with what should have been my original question.

Comment: Never mind, you gave me the answer as well. Using `reset` gives me the same behaviour. Thank you!

Comment: @TomasBerger Answer revised.

Comment: @songyuanyao I see I have misunderstood smart pointer, I just thought of it as a replacement for C styled pointer in general (With the nice bonus of managing the object). A follow-up; Would using `reset` be bad? The pointer is in scope as long as the program is running

Comment: @TomasBerger next reset call or call to destructor will try to `delete` pointer you submitted. If it wasn't a pointer from new expression... that's screwed. Note that unique_ptr also cannot be copied. It is meant to be a single point of ownership.

Comment: @TomasBerger As Swift-FridayPie explained, using `reset` here is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` is a wrapper over a raw pointer and memory allocation mechanism. And it is more about memory allocation. It was designed to create and destroy objects automatically.

This line:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<const int>(5);
```

is equivalent to:

```
auto ptr = new const int{5};
```

So in your line

```
ptr1 = std::make_unique<const int>(getValue());
```

ptr1 points to a new object of type const int, initialized with the value returned by getValue().

And you don't change this value in your program. If you tried like this:

```
*ptr.get() += 1;
```

you'll get compilation error, because int is const.